# Why is validating an IP giving me invalid with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ip

Here is my model:

```
require 'resolv'
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  @ip_regex = /^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$/

  validates :ip, :dns, :ntp, :format => { :with => @ip_regex } 
  validates_format_of :ip, :dns, :ntp, :with => Resolv::IPv4::Regex

end
```

As you can see, I am trying two ways, both of which are giving me:

```
xxx is invalid
```

For input, I am simply trying: `192.168.1.1`.

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7, and Rails 3.0.3.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: The regex matches 192.168.1.1

Comment: I know, that is why I am unsure why RoR is spitting that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPv6 is going to become more and more prevalent since the IPv4 space is exhausted. Rather than relying on an IPv4 regex, use IPAddr and rely on a well-tested wheel to tell you whether it's a valid IP, regardless of it being IPv4 or v6.

IPAddr will raise:

```
IPAddr::InvalidAddressError: invalid address
```

for something like:

```
require 'ipaddr'
IPAddr.new('292.168.1.1')
```

If it's a valid v4 or v6 it will pass.

---

Regarding why Rails is rejecting an IP number: You have two separate validations going on, but you don't show which is raising the error you see. Basic debugging says to comment out one and see whether the problem disappears or continues to happen. Once you do that you can dig in deeper to figure out the problem. As is, you don't give us any information about which line Rails is complaining about.

Comment: Turns out for some reason, it was still an integer even though I rolled back and re-migrated?

Comment: *WHAT* was an integer? This makes no sense.

Comment: @theTinMan The IPv6 advice is great, but do you understand why his test was failing? In any event, I'd be interested in your assessment of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`validates_format_of` is just a variant of `validates`. It expects an actual regex, as you've supplied in your `validates` call. Since you're just supplying the `Regex` *class*, I suspect it's nullifying your otherwise valid `validates` call.